# wordpress image error message

Tags: javascript, wordpress

```
wp:featuredimage [{code: "rest_forbidden", message: "Sorry, you are not allowed to do that.", data: {status: 403}}
```

I don't get the solution for this kind of error. Need help.

Comment: You're not giving us much to work with here.  What's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have file name having accented characters (â, î, ô, é, è etc.) ?

Due to such accented character presented in the file name might have issue of what you are getting now.

If so then please rename all those accented character then it might work.

Thank You

Comment: How would a 403 Access Denied response depend on the file name of the uploaded image?